# why prev() and .siblings() both are not work in the context?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="menu2">
<li><a href="/term/6">close/show</a>
<ul class="haschild">
<li><a href="/term/14">test 1 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/term/13">tst 13</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/term/7">helli</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery code:

```
  $("ul.haschild").hide();
  $("ul.haschild").prev().click(function(){
    $(this).children('.haschild').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

when click the **close/show**, the **haschild** part doesn't change between in show or hide.

then i change `$("ul.haschild").prev()` to `$("ul.haschild").siblings()` it still can't work.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the clicked element doesn't have `.haschild` descendant element, you can use `next` method:

```
$(this).next('.haschild').slideToggle('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tk9j8/

Note that you should put your code within document ready handler.